# Adding Generic Inquiry to 2017 R2 Menu

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to add a normal generic inquiry to the modern menu of Acumatica 2017 R2. Every time I try to customize the menu, I can't see my generic inquiry. There is nothing special about the inquiry.

I created the Generic Inquiry through the Generic Inquiry BLC interface. It is currently bound in the Site Map to Company -> Organization -> Customer Management -> reports -> Business Accounts. I've also placed it in Hidden -> Primary Lists, but I still couldn't place it somewhere on the menu. If I switch back to the old UI, I can see it where it sites on the Site Map.

This Generic Inquiry is not meant to be an Entry Point to any page. I just want it to be a normal, stand-alone Generic Inquiry that the user can go to strictly to view information. (Basically use it like in the old menu, just to show a table of information.)

Comment: Please, add more information about your generic inquire. Like how you created it and where is it bound in sitemap

Comment: I've added some information. Please let me know if you need any other specific information. I'm not sure what else to add at this time.

Comment: Can you please tell me how are you trying to add it in the Modern UI?

Comment: Through the ... -> Edit Menu option at the bottom of the left navigation bar.

Comment: Can you please add the screenshot of the Select Forms popup with Search equal to the name of your Inquiry page  which appear after clicking on the **ADD MENU ITEM** at the top

Comment: Well for some odd reason I can now see the GI and select it to add it to my menu. I'm not sure how this happened what so ever. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I just waited an X amount of time, and it now appears to allow me to select it and add it to the screen. I've done everything from assign it to multiple different locations on the site map including where the Entry Page GIs are located. I've also added the GI to my customization project, published, reset IIS, republished, re-reset the IIS and it still didn't show. I also logged out and back in multiple times with no luck. It just seemed like time is what fixed it. If anyone has any advice to make it show up without waiting, please add your answer, otherwise one just has to wait.